# What are the steps to calibrate iMac display with Spyder 3 Pro?

Tags: display-calibration, spyder3

I need to calibrate the display on my iMac and have got a Spyder 3 Pro to do this with. However, the standard brightness of the iMac screen is **very** bright, do I need to turn the brightness down before calibrating?

I realise I can pay £60 for an upgrade to Spyder Elite 4.0 which allows for screen brightness control, but I'd rather not spend the money if the Spyder 3 Pro can do the job as standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you calibrate the monitor, set it to the brightness that you will run it at when you are using it for editing photos. If you find full brightness uncomfortably bright, turn it down.

The important thing is just that it be consistent. (always edit your photos at the same brightness as it was calibrated for).

I have a Huey pro (same idea as the spyder), and use it for my MacBook Pro using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the onscreen instructions.  I believe that the Spyder software instructs one to set the brightness to the midpoint (50%) level.

Comment: It states "Set brightness to a level you are comfortable with", I'm going to see how it goes at that and maybe upgrade later.